# Changing data as tabs are clicked in vue-chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, vue-chartjs

I am using vue-chartjs on a page. I created a tab system. When tab-items are clicked, the content changes. I want to update the data of the line chart when tab-items are clicked, but I couldn't manage to do it so far. Below, I shared my code, and I also added the code for the file containing the data to the JavaScript part

```js
export const data = {
  labels: ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Total 1',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderColor: '#3E97FF',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#3E97FF',
      pointBorderColor: '#101929',
      pointRadius: 6,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      data: [140, 170, 120, 140, 150, 200, 140, 100, 80, 40, 50, 30],
    },
    {
      label: 'Total 2',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderColor: '#3E97FF',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#3E97FF',
      pointBorderColor: '#101929',
      pointRadius: 6,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      data: [140, 170, 120, 140, 150, 300, 140, 100, 80, 40, 50, 30],
    }
  ],
};
```

```html
<template>
  <Line ref="lineChart" :data="data" :options="options" />
          
  <div class="chart-after">
    <div class="title">
      {{ tabContents[currentTab].title }}
    </div>
    <div class="amount">
      <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="start">{{ tabContents[currentTab].start }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="end">{{ tabContents[currentTab].end }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
        
  <div class="charts-tabs">
    <div class="tab-item" v-for="(tab, index) in tabContents" :key="index" @click="changeTab(index)">
      {{ tab.label }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Chart as ChartJS, CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs';
import * as chartConfig from './lineChartConfig.js';

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend);

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: '#101929',
    },
  },
  scales: {
    y: {
      grid: {
        borderColor: 'transparent',
      },
      ticks: {
        color: '#323C52',
      },
    },
    x: {
      grid: {
        color: '#1C2941',
      },
      ticks: {
        color: '#323C52',
      },
    },
  },
};

export default {
  components: {
    Line,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      data: chartConfig.data,
      options: options,
      tabContents: [
        {
          label: '1',
          title: 'Tab 1 İçerik',
          start: '10M $',
          end: '5M $',
        },
        {
          label: '2',
          title: 'Tab 2 İçerik',
          start: '20M $',
          end: '15M $',
        },
        {
          label: '3',
          title: 'Tab 3 İçerik',
          start: '30M $',
          end: '25M $',
        },
        {
          label: '4',
          title: 'Tab 4 İçerik',
          start: '40M $',
          end: '35M $',
        },
      ],
      currentTab: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeTab(index) {
      this.currentTab = index;
      console.log(this.data.datasets[0]);
      this.data.datasets[0].data = chartConfig.data[index]; 
    },
  },
};
</script>
```